# download a file after rendering a template in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to download a csv file and rendering a template at the same time after redirecting from a view but it only downloads the file ,doesn't render the template.
I think it can be handled by middleware but finding an easier solution to it.

```
class ProductUploadView(FormView):
    template_name ='upload.html'
    form_class = csvform
    success_url = 'response/'
    failed_rows = []

    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        form  = self.form_class(request.POST,request.FILES)
        file = request.FILES['csvfile']
        csvfile = csv.reader(utf_8_encoder(file), dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
        csvfile.next()

        for row in csvfile:
            if row[1] in ['PRES','GEN','GEN'] and row[2] in ['CAPS','TAB','SYP','GEL','SUSP','INJ']:
                try:
                    p, created = Product.objects.get_or_create(brand_name=row[0], category=row[1], defaults={'form': row[2], 'mrp': row[3], 'ptr': row[4]})
                except ValidationError:
                    self.failed_rows.append(row)
                    pass
            else:
                self.failed_rows.append(row)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)


class UploadedView(ProductUploadView):
    template_name = 'response.html'
    rows = ProductUploadView.failed_rows

    def download_view(self,request):
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'
        writer = csv.writer(response)
        writer.writerows(self.rows)
        return response

    def get(self,request):
        response = TemplateResponse(request,self.template_name,{'num':len(self.rows),'failed_rows':self.rows})
        response.add_post_render_callback(download_view)
        return response
```

Comment: You can not send an HTML document and a file to download in response to one single HTTP request. The way this is usually done, is you return your HTML document, and that then automatically triggers a second request for the file download, for example via a meta refresh or by changing the location via JavaScript.

Comment: Also, you **must not** try and store data between requests in class attributes. That is unsafe: any user will see that data. Use the database, or the session.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I am new to django and don't know how to trigger download after rendering the template . I would appreciate any solutions to that. Thank you

Comment: @DanielRoseman can u please elaborate ?